# Three boxes HTML / CSS design

Tags: html, css

I would like to build three boxes for my website like the following :
[image]

My wish is that the height of boxes 1 & 3 would be equal to the size of box 2, and that this height is  expressed in percentage relatively to the parent element.
What I've tried so far : 
- Box 1 & 3 with `display: inline-block;` property
- Box 1 & 2 & 3 with fixed height attributes
But I've never managed to have the proper scheme. Can someone explain me how to achieve this ?

Comment: Please provide your sample code

Comment: Could you please provide the code block. It will help in understanding what you have done so far.

Comment: use either flex box  or  display table cell

Comment: Take a look at [css grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

Answer (score -1):

The link is broken and no codes been provided, so we can't see visually what it is you are trying to achieve.

But i suggest you look into Flexbox because it offers more flexibility in layout control compared to the more-traditional block/inline-block (+float). Css tricks has a comprehensive guide on everything flexbox.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/